# por que jquery está retornando repeteco de informações?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, delegate

Eu estou usando o comando

```
$("div").delegate( ".btnAcessoAtividade", "click", function()
{ 
    var id =  $(this).attr('id');                                                                     
    window.localStorage.setItem("id",id);
    console.log( $(this) );
    $('.reunioes').prepend( window.localStorage.getItem('id') );});
```

porque eu quero pegar o id da seguinte estrutura:

```
$(".reunioes").append(
    "<div class='btnAcessoAtividade' id ='*"+response.data[i].id+"'>"
    +"<span class='nome'> "+response.data[i].deal_title+"</span>"
    +"<span class='hora'>"+response.data[i].due_time+"</span>"
    +"</div>"
);
```

só que por algum motivo, está trazendo o "id" 3 vezes...vem dessa forma:

> init [div#*14174.btnAcessoAtividade, context:
>   div#*14174.btnAcessoAtividade] init [div#*14174.btnAcessoAtividade,
>   context: div#*14174.btnAcessoAtividade]
>   init [div#*14174.btnAcessoAtividade, context:
>   div#*14174.btnAcessoAtividade]

porque isso acontece? o que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Porque você tem três elementos com a classe btnAcessoAtividade?

Comment: oi, Leandro, não entendi sua colocação...eu tenho a classe principal , que é a "reunioes", dentro dela, são várias classes(elementos) "btnAcessoAtividade" como se fossem "linhas"...cada linha, com seu id...mas da forma que aparece e que eu postei,quem repete, são os ids

Comment: Fica difícil precisar seu erro exatamente sem o restante do código e do HTML. Dá pra ter uma ideia do erro mas sem precisão. Se tiver um `for`, você provavelmente está aplicando o mesmo ID a diversos botões. Ou você tem mais de uma classe `.reunioes` (no caso, 3).

Answer (score 0):

Tente adicionar o event listener em cada elemento, não na lista de retorno com múltiplos elementos. Estou utilizando `on` como exemplo porque `delegate` já está defasado.

```
$("div .btnAcessoAtividade").each(function(i, el) {
    $(el).on('click', clickBtnAcessoAtividade);
});

function clickBtnAcessoAtividade(evt) {
    var id =  $(this).attr('id');                                                                     
    window.localStorage.setItem("id",id);
    console.log( $(this) );
    $('.reunioes').prepend( window.localStorage.getItem('id'));
}
```